# Why does script run in Firefox, but not IE8?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a script that runs OK in Firefox.

The script does not run in Internet Explorer. I would be grateful for assistance.

Here are first few lines:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

URL = "http://google.com/"

class TestGoogle < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    #@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
  end

  def testSignInLink
    @browser.goto URL
```

Here are selected error messages:

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)     C:/RubymineProjects/ditto/Google_01_TU_03.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-classic/version.rb:3:             warning: already initialized constant VERSION
...
...
  1) Error:
testSignInLink(TestGoogle):
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class UnknownObjectException
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-    classic/exceptions.rb:12:in `<module:Exception>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-    classic/exceptions.rb:2:in `<module:Watir>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-classic/exceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-classic.rb:6:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.7.0/lib/watir-classic.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-4.0.2-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:48:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-4.0.2-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:48:in `load_driver'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-4.0.2-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:40:in `load_driver_for'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-4.0.2-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:8:in `new'
C:/RubymineProjects/ditto/Google_01_TU_03.rb:11:in `setup'
```

Line 11 is:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
```

Comment: You should not require both Watir and Watir-webdriver in the same script. Not sure it's the source of your problem, but it ain't helping much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @abe comment, I did the following.

For IE only, I removed "require 'watir'". That worked fine.

Restore "require 'watir'". Remove "require 'watir-webdriver'".  That worked fine.

That's the answer to my question. But I don't understand that. It sounds as if the two APIs are interchangeable  :)

Comment: They are two separate libraries.  If I were going to be testing mostly through IE then I'd probably use watir. If I were going to test through all browsers then I'd probably use watur-webriver.